# While converting Array of array in ruby to hash hash does not include all the keys but takes the last one

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

This is an array which i want to convert into a hash

```
a = [[1, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2]]
```

but the hash i am getting is

```
2.2.0 :004 > a.to_h
=> {1=>2, 3=>2}
```

why is it so?

Comment: Same for me in Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: ...@Ursus, your comments will be puzzling to readers now that the OP has corrected the typo. I suggest you delete your comments (and I'll delete mine.)

Comment: A hash maps a key to a value. What else is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hashes have unique keys. [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) is effectively doing the following:

```
h = {}.merge(1=>3).merge(3=>2).merge(1=>2)
  #=> { 1=>3 }.merge(3=>2).merge(1=>2)
  #=> { 1=>3, 3=>2 }.merge(1=>2)
  #=> { 1=>2, 3=>2 }
```

In the last merge the value of the key `1` (`3`) is replaced with `2`.

Note that

```
h.merge(k=>v)
```

is (permitted) shorthand for

```
h.merge({ k=>v })
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys of a Hash are basically a Set, so no duplicate keys are allowed.
If two pairs are present in your Array with the same first element, only the last pair will be kept in the Hash.

If you want to keep the whole information, you could define arrays as values :

```
a = [[1, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2]]
hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}
p a.each_with_object(hash) { |(k, v), h| h[k] << v }
#=> {1=>[3, 2], 3=>[2]}
```

Here's a shorter but less common way to define it :

```
hash = a.each_with_object(Hash.new{[]}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] <<= v }
```

Calling `hash[1]` returns `[3,2]`, which are all the second elements from the pairs of your array having `1` as first element.